# Code to change button color isn't working

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some code for changing a button color within the button click function itself that works just fine.

```
_5.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, 180, 20, 30));
```

But when I try to call _5 from another form using an object reference, nothing happens despite it compiling correctly.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {           
            MainWindow b = new MainWindow();
            b._5.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, 180, 20, 30));
        }
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing incorrectly please?

Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;



namespace SBI_Mgt_System
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void _1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            Room1 openRoom = new Room1();
            openRoom.Show();
            rooms x = new rooms();
            x.Show();
        }

        public void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Room1 openRoom = new Room1();
            openRoom.Show();
            rooms x = new rooms();
            x.Show();
        }

        public void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Room1 openRoom = new Room1();
            openRoom.Show();
            rooms x = new rooms();
            x.Show();
        }

        public void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Room1 openRoom = new Room1();
            openRoom.Show();
            rooms x = new rooms();
            x.Show();
        }

        public void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Room1 openRoom = new Room1();
            openRoom.Show();
            rooms x = new rooms();
            x.Show();
        }

        public void Button_Click_4(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Room1 openRoom = new Room1();
            openRoom.Show();
            rooms x = new rooms();
            x.Show();
        }

        public void Button_Click_5(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Room1 openRoom = new Room1();
            openRoom.Show();
            rooms x = new rooms();
            x.Show();              
        }
   }
}
```

The other form...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SBI_Mgt_System
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for rooms.xaml
    /// </summary>

    public partial class rooms : Window
    {
        public static bool res = false;

        public rooms()
        {
            InitializeComponent();    

        }


        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            this.Close();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {           
            MainWindow b = new MainWindow();
            b._5.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, 180, 20, 30));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Visual Studio IDE application, so I've removed that tag.

Comment: FYI, `MainWindow b = new MainWindow();` creates a new instance of `MainWindow`. It's like buying another of the same year/make/model as your current car, and turning the air conditioning on in the new car with the expectation that it will turn on the air conditioning in your original car. It won't because they are different vehicles.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
MainWindow b = new MainWindow();
```

You're creating a new instance of `MainWindow` and modifying that, not the instance that is actually visible to the user. If you called `b.Show()` you'd see the new instance show up.

To do what you want to do, you need to reference the already-existing window. Here, the [documentation for `Window.Show()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.show?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) can help:

> A window that is opened by calling Show does not automatically have a relationship with the window that opened it; specifically, the opened window does not know which window opened it. This relationship can be established using the Owner property and managed using the OwnedWindows property.

From there we can look at the documentation for [`Window.Owner`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.owner?view=netframework-4.8), which has a [code example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.owner?view=netframework-4.8#examples). You can do this when you show the new window:

```cs
rooms x = new rooms();
x.Owner = this;
x.Show();
```

That gives you a reference to the main window in the `Owner` property. So then, in your `rooms` class, you can do this:

```cs
((MainWindow) Owner)._5.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, 180, 20, 30));
```

I assume you are actually declaring this `_5` property somewhere, since you didn't show it in your code. That's a terrible name for a property by the way :)

Comment: I hate looking stupid on here, but here goes...
Was I not declaring _5 in its button_click method?

Comment: You didn't declare it there, but if it's a button then it would be created and declared by the code generated by the designer. So ignore that part - you're good there :)